# OSError: [Errno 10048] error while attempting to bind on address

Tags: python, aiohttp

```
OSError: [Errno 10048] error while attempting to bind on address ('0.0.0.0', 8080): only one usage of e
ach socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
```

I have installed aiohttp and as mentioned in a tutorial,
I tried to run the script using 
`python main.py` command

```
from aiohttp import web
async def index(request):
    return web.Response(text='Hello Aiohttp!')
app = web.Application()
web.run_app(app)
```

I get this error and don't know how to sort this issue.

Any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: Sounds like something else is already listening on that port (8080) - try changing it to some other number (e.g. 9090)

Comment: please can i know how can we change that in aiohttp ,because im completely new to it

Comment: Have you had a look at the documentation? Quick start? Tried googling for 'set port aiohttp'?

Comment: tried googling but its of no use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web_reference.html#aiohttp.web.run_app .You can pass the port as

```
from aiohttp import web
async def index(request):
    return web.Response(text='Hello Aiohttp!')
app = web.Application()
web.run_app(app, port=9090)
```

Answer (score 3):

Issue with your problem is some process is already running on 8080 port number.
There are two ways to solve problem

1. sudo kill `sudo lsof -t -i:8080` (if you are working on ubuntu) or
   `sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:8080)`
2. `python -m aiohttp.web -H localhost -P 5050 package.module.init_func`

   `package.module.init_func` should be an importable callable that accepts a list of any non-parsed command-line arguments and returns an `Application` instance after setting it up:

   ```
   def init_function(argv):
       app = web.Application()
       app.router.add_route("GET", "/", index_handler)
       return app
   ```

hopefully above solution may will help you.

you can go through documentation of aiohttp to know more about it.
https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/v0.21.5/web.html